# How do IIS understand or know my timeout duration?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I have a asp.net web api where is host on IIS and I use restsharp for request operations. I also added a timeout for requests. So far everything is normal.

When i did a load test to my api, some requests queued on IIS, I saw these requests at worker process screen on IIS. How can i kill these processes automatically or how do IIS understand or know my timeout duration ? I have a timeout whereas it doesn' t work.

[image]

```
IRestClient _client = new RestClient(url) { Timeout = timeout};
```

Comment: Where did you add the timeout? on the client side? IIS cannot see that timeout.

Comment: @Ben I added to my asp.net web api on my restsharp implementation.

Comment: Is the restsharp call executed from within IIS or is it separate being used to call IIS?

Comment: @Ben, Yes the restsharp is call executed from within IIS.

Comment: Is it calling into the same instance of IIS?

Comment: Your description is ambiguous. Do you make calls to the same Web API from within? If so, that can easily exhaust the thread pool under burst load, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/821268/contention-poor-performance-and-deadlocks-when-you-make-calls-to-web-s Of course, you need a profiler right now to better understand the issue (IIS Manager is of very limited usage on that).

Comment: @Ben Yes,our api like proxy, both producer and consumer.

Comment: @LexLi Yes, i make calls to the same web api to another apis. I will check your documentation.

Comment: If it's calling to the same AppPool you are in process, so don't use REST, you will consume all your threadpool and get thread starvation. Just make a direct call.